# Arise from the dead vs Rise from the dead

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-difference

In some sources they use *"Rise from the dead"* while in others *"Arise from the dead"*

According to dictionaries (different ones):

- **Rise** - be resurrected: in some beliefs, to become resurrected after death 
  rise from the dead
- **Arise** - to appear or come into existence, become active or vocal: to rise from a quiet, inactive, or subjugated state to become active, vocal, or rebellious (literary).

The [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rise+from+the+dead) says *"Rise from the dead"* is an idiom, yet I can see that [Sleeping Saints](http://sounddoctrine.net/Nick/Ephesians/sleeping_saints.htm) by By Pastor Nick Bibile uses *"arise"* and [AWAKE! ARISE FROM THE DEAD!](http://www.wacriswell.org/PrintTranscript.cfm/SID/2203.cfm) by Dr.  W.  A.  Criswell and a song [Arise from the dead](https://cradleofgod.bandcamp.com/track/arise-from-the-dead)  by Cradle of God also use *"arise"*.

So what does *"Arise from the dead"* mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Rise* and *arise* are close synonyms, although *arise* has another meaning that you have already given. They can both be used to mean "get up", and have very similar etymologies as can be seen below.

Older translations of the Bible certainly use *arise* as an injunction, as can be seen in Bibile's quotation from [Ephesians 5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=eph+5&version=ESV) (English Standard Version):

> “Awake, O sleeper,
>   and **arise** from the dead,
>   and Christ will shine on you.”

This is very much in the poetic register, and the translator makes full use of the alliteration that the usage provides. There is also, perhaps, an allusion to both meanings of *arise*, i.e. to "get up" from the dead, and also to "come into existence" from the dead.

Helpfully, Bibile also quotes from [Isaiah 60](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isaiah+60&version=ESV), where both meanings of *arise* are also employed:

> **Arise**, shine, for your light has come,
>   and the glory of the Lord has risen upon you.
>   For behold, darkness shall cover the earth,
>   and thick darkness the peoples;
>   but the Lord will **arise** upon you,
>   and his glory will be seen upon you.
>   And nations shall come to your light,
>   and kings to the brightness of your rising.

It may be useful, when reading older translations of the Bible, to look for both meanings whenever you come across the usage of *arise*.

Finally, some useful comments are made in [Biblical Hermeneutics.SE](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/what-scripture-is-paul-referring-to-in-ephesians-514) on Isaiah 60:1, where a literal translation from the Hebrew is given as "Rise and shine!", a (still current) English idiom meaning "Wake up, and get out of bed."

[Online Etymology Dictionary: rise](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rise)
[Online Etymology Dictionary: arise](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=arise)

Comment: I remember meating "Rise and shine" in Half-life 2 (Game). I know it very well. So is "Arise from the dead" an idiom too?

Comment: the "a-" prefix here is an old one meaning "up, out, away" and functioned as an intensifier (originally). It's similar to resurrect in the original Latin since the "re-" means "again, back" and act intensively, but "resurrecturus" and "surrecturus" mean the same thing effectively.